# Solving the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos(x) \, dx $

Tags: definite-integrals

> **Problem.** Calculate
> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos(x) \, dx $$

I was recommended to calculate it using limits, but firstly I have solved the integral and I got

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\cos(x) \, dx = \frac{\sin(x) - \cos(x)}{2e^x}. $$

I don't know how to calculate limit as $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: As $x$ tends to $\infty$, $ e^x \rightarrow \infty$, and as $-\sqrt{2}\le sin(x)-cos(x)\le \sqrt{2}$, your limit tends to 0.

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Comment: I think you mean you got $$ \int_0^x e^{-t}\cos(t)\,{\rm d}t=\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{2e^x}. $$ The dummy variable of definite integral does not appear outside of it, and a single-variable definite integral is a constant, not a function.

Comment: @JudeCarter Note that $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - x} \cos x\,{\rm d}x}  = \frac{1}{2}.
$$ More generally, $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - ax} \cos (bx)\,{\rm d}x}  = \frac{a}{{a^2  + b^2 }}
$$ for $\operatorname{Re}(a)>0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$.